# Get annotations from jqassistant after maven repository scan

Tags: java, maven, annotations, jqassistant

I scanned my Maven repository with JQassistant. Now I would like to find out which classes are annotated by @Stateful. But even using

```
MATCH (a:Java:Value:Annotation) RETURN DISTINCT a.name
```

returns no rows as result. Are annotations not a part of repository scanning? Or do I write a wrong query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following query will return all classes annotated by @Stateful

```
MATCH
  (t:Type)-[:ANNOTATED_BY]->()-[:OF_TYPE]->(statefulType:Type)
WHERE
  statefulType.fqn = "javax.ejb.Stateful"
RETURN
  t.fqn
```

If you've scanned a repository it might be useful to also return the artifact that contains these types:

```
MATCH
  (a:Artifact)-[:CONTAINS]->(t:Type),
  (t)-[:ANNOTATED_BY]->()-[:OF_TYPE]->(statefulType:Type)
WHERE
  statefulType.fqn = "javax.ejb.Stateful"
RETURN
  a.fqn, collect(t.fqn)
```

Comment: That works, thank you. Do you know why my query does not return any rows?

Comment: Ok, probably because the Java:Value:Annotation has no content.

Comment: Just verified your first query - the cause is that the scanner did not add the Java label to the annotation node but the documentation proposes that it's there. I've created an issue (https://github.com/buschmais/jqassistant/issues/378), will be fixed with the next release.